# Python pandas map CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I want to "merge" two CSV files. I want to map the emails from the File 1 and get their respective userId from File 2 then I want to assign it to the respective emails of File 1

Example:

File 1

```
name, userId, email
john, null, john@a.com
alex, null, alex@a.com
micheal, null, mike@a.com
alex, null, alex@a.com
john, null, john@a.com
```

File 2

```
name, userId, email
alex, 5, alex@a.com
micheal, 10, mike@a.com
john, 12, john@a.com
```

Output File

```
name, userId, email
john, 12, john@a.com
alex, 5, alex@a.com
micheal, 10, mike@a.com
alex, 5, alex@a.com
john, 12, john@a.com
```

This is my code but this doesn't assign the userId of the respective email because emails are not ordered

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", sep=",")
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", sep=",", index_col=0)

df1["userId"] = df2["userId"].values

df1.to_csv("output.csv", sep=";")
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Dataframe.join is what you're looking for: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dataframe.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", sep=",")
df1.columns = ['name', 'userid', 'email']
df2 = pd.read_csv("file2.csv", sep=",", index_col=0)
df1 = df1.drop(['userId'], axis=1)

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['name','email'], how='right')

result.to_csv("output.csv", sep=";")
```

How I tested:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['john', 'alex', 'michael', 'alex', 'john'],
                    'userId': ['null', 'null', 'null', 'null', 'null'],
                    'email': ['john@a.com', 'alex@a.com', 'mike@a.com', 'alex@a.com', 'john@a.com']
                    }, columns=['name','userId','email'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['alex', 'michael', 'john'],
                    'userId': ['5', '10', '12'],
                    'email': ['alex@a.com', 'mike@a.com', 'john@a.com']
                    })

df1 = df1.drop(['userId'], axis=1)

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['name','email'], how='right')

print(df1)
print(df2)

print(result)
```

Comment: I don't get the expected output, could you please try it?

Comment: Switched to the merge method, hopefully it works for you! Change the `how='outer'` to `how='inner'` to have list of only length df2.

Answer (score 1):

So I think if you drop the UserID field from File 1 and drop name from File 2.  Then merge the two dataframes on email address and you should get the